# Loop unrolling in inlined functions in C for speed optimized multiple register multiple bit access

Tags: c, optimization, inline, loop-unrolling

I have a question how to most elegantly solve following problem related to discrete IO checks of a micro controller:

Contents of .c file:

---

```
struct transfers {
uint32t *RegisterAddr;
uint8_t RegBit;
};

static const struct transfers DIO[] = {
{ REGA_ADDR, 3},
{ NULL, 1},
{ NULL, 12},
{ REGB_ADDR, 2},
{ NULL, 7},
{ REGC_ADDR, 5},
{ REGD_ADDR, 1}
};

inline uint32t Dinputs(const uint8_t n){

  uint32_t DIO_Data = 0;
  uint32_t RegData;

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    if (DIO[i].RegisterAddr != NULL) RegData = *DIO[i].RegisterAddr;

    if ((RegData & (1 << DIO[i].RegBit)) == 0) DIO_Data |= (1 << i);
  }
  return DIO_Data;
}

void testfunction(void) {

  uint32_t DIO_Data = Dinputs(N_USED);
}
```

---

Expected result after compilation with --O3 --funroll-loops
shall be speed optimized such as the following equivalent C-Code for testfunction, provided that N_USED is defined to be 7 and REGx_ADDR are also defined to be valid register addresses:

```
  uint32_t DIO_Data = 0;
  uint32_t RegData;

  RegData = *REGA_ADDR;
  if ((RegData & (1 << 3)) == 0) IO_Data |= (1 << 0);
  if ((RegData & (1 << 1)) == 0) IO_Data |= (1 << 1);
  if ((RegData & (1 << 12)) == 0) IO_Data |= (1 << 2);
  RegData = *REGB_ADDR;
  if ((RegData & (1 << 2)) == 0) IO_Data |= (1 << 3);
  if ((RegData & (1 << 7)) == 0) IO_Data |= (1 << 4);
  RegData = *REGC_ADDR;
  if ((RegData & (1 << 5)) == 0) IO_Data |= (1 << 5);
  RegData = *REGD_ADDR;
  if ((RegData & (1 << 1)) == 0) IO_Data |= (1 << 6);
```

I use the GCC compiler for ARM v7. Does this work as expected, with optimized machine code output when using the above inline function Dinputs called by testfunction? Is there a possibility to enforce the unroll and the inlining of the Dinputs function? Not really important, but for curiosity: since the struct transfers DIO in the above example is only used by the unrolled inline function, it would not be necessary for the compiler to take over this data into the data section of the object file. What is the expected behaviour wrt. this?

The reason that I do not want to use the equivalent code in my project is, that this would require many additional preprocessor commands if N_USED shall be in the range of 0 to 7 (in this example) at compile time, and variants using other DIO tables are more easily definable by just exchanging the tables and not any the code.

Comment: So, what did you do to find out? Checked the Assembler? Profile? Why do you care in the first place? Always concentrate on writing readable and **correct** code! Don't do premature optimisations if they defy these primary goals. Optimise hotspots **after** profiling. And ARMv7 is actually three very different families. Which one do you use?

Comment: Sidenote: Optimise your hardware first. The code above is only required because the hardware connections have been messed up. It is very well the task of the software-developer to review the hardware connections and have a serious talk with the hardware-designer. So the most elegant option is to possibly kick bu** (verbally!).

Comment: And use unsigned integers of appropriate type when shifting!

Comment: I did not perform any tests up to know, since I would first like to understand if this kind of compiler optimization is possible or not.